# How can I restore the pactl to its default configurations (huge noise on loopback)?

Tags: pulseaudio

I've been using the following command to be able to hear myself on the microphone:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1
```

I got this line on this [issue](https://askubuntu.com/a/262297/1153225)... This command always worked fine, but today I was playing around with changing the pitch of the voice as described in this other [issue](https://askubuntu.com/a/425544/1153225). Basically, I was using commands like:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink
sox -t pulseaudio default -t pulseaudio null pitch -800
```

I'm not sure when things went wrong, but now everytime I use the command `pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1` I hear a huge noise and it's not working anymore... I've tried purging all tools that I used, and installing them again... rebooting the computer... but I've not managed to make it go back as it was before, all the times I use the command to hear my own voice there's a huge noise on my phones (the microphone and audio work fine in others situations though)... What would be the default procedure to follow when we completely mess up our PulseAudio configuration? I'd like to be able to execute the first command again...

Comment: Check your microphone sound level ... it is most likely pumped up to the max. Bring it down and this should do.

Comment: @Raffa Thanks, that was really the issue... In my case, if the microphone is higher than 75% of its capacity and I use the loopback command it makes that loud noise... I've probably changed it to 100% accidentally somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`module-loopback` routes your input(microphone) to your output(speakers) ... What you describe is common and expected ... Check your microphone sound level ... It is most likely bumped up to the max ... Bring it down and this should do.